# Show suggestion in VS property window for a custom control property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-controls

I have developed a custom control with two public property called ListField and DataSource.

ListField property must be set to the name of a property of the object contained in DataSource.

It's possible to configure ListField in a way that when setting the properties in Visual Studio property window, I get a list suggesting the values of all properties in the DataSource object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) to define a custom editor for your property (at design time).

Here's some links:

- [**Walkthrough:
  Implementing UITypeEditor
  (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx)
- [**How To: Create a
  Windows Forms Control That Takes
  Advantage of Design-Time Features
  (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/307hck25.aspx)